# Tycho feature/plugin build with platform specific fragments plugins included

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I am trying to update the build process for Subclipse to use Eclipse Tycho.

Subclipse has an Eclipse plugin - javahl which has two fragment plugins, one for win32 and one for win64 which add Windows-specific DLL's that the plugin needs in the path.

My master pom.xml has this in it:

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
    <configuration>
     <resolver>p2</resolver>
     <environments>
      <environment>
       <os>win32</os>
       <ws>win32</ws>
       <arch>x86</arch>
      </environment>
      <environment>
       <os>win32</os>
       <ws>win32</ws>
       <arch>x86_64</arch>
      </environment>
     </environments>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

When I try to include these fragment plugins in the build it fails like this:

```
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.tigris.subclipse:org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win32:1.8.15-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/markphip/git/subclipse/bundles/svnapi.javahl.win32/.polyglot.build.properties
[INFO] {osgi.os=win32, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86_64, osgi.ws=win32}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Problems resolving provisioning plan.:
[ERROR]      org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win32 1.8.15.qualifier cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.
```

I am running the build on OSX, eventually it will run in TravisCI on Linux.

My ultimate goal is just to build and package everything into a p2 repository I can post to bintray.  So I need these fragments to build and be included in the final p2 repository.

The fragments just have something like this in the MANIFEST

```
Fragment-Host: org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl;bundle-version="[1.8.0,1.9.0)"
Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86_64))
```

And the feature likewise has similar filters:

```
  <plugin
         id="org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win32"
         os="win32"
         arch="x86"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         fragment="true"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64"
         os="win32"
         arch="x86_64"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         fragment="true"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the `os="win32" for the win64 correct? I'm note sure?

Comment: It is what I always have used and Vogella has it in their example so I assume so

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out by finding some eclipse.org plugins that needed to do the same thing.

I am using the pomless feature of Tycho.  It looks like that does not support this scenario, so I just had to add a pom.xml to my fragment plugins so that I could specify the tycho configuration for each.

Comment: What was the fix?

Comment: The fix is what I mentioned.  The issue was just that the pomless Tycho does not support this yet, so I had to add a pom.xml to the fragments so that I could specify the architecture for the build.

Comment: I'm haven trouble with the same problem - just did as you, but fail to build the feature as it does not seem to care for the plug-in filter variables. Could you provide a sample on the pom.xml you added to the fragments?

Comment: It has been a few years. Maybe this? https://github.com/subclipse/javahl-windows/blob/master/bundles/svnapi.javahl.win32/pom.xml